# How can I copy a custom Dictionary on Word 2000?

Tags: microsoft-word, dictionary

How do I copy custom dictionary on word 2000 onto a flash drive and then copy it to custom dictionary word 2003 on my new computer?

Answer (score 4):

This explains all about custom dictionaries at: http://www.kerryr.net/webwriting/tools_custom-dicts.htm

The file you need is `custom.dic` and can be found at:

- Win XP:
  `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Microsoft\Proof\custom.dic`
- Win Vista and Win 7:
  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Proof\custom.dic`
- Win 7 with additional Office Proofing Tools Kit:
  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UProof\custom.dic`

You will need to enable **Show hidden files and folders** to find it. Simply replace the `custom.dic` on your new PC/Office with that one and it should work.

Comment: You're welcome, consider accepting the answer if it worked out for you! ;)